# Summarizing a paper to give a different meaning

Tags: single-word-requests, citation, paraphrasing

A recent news article published an article based on certain research. They included the link to the research. However, both the title of the article, and the conclusions it drew, ran contrary to the researcher's findings. The article deliberately paraphrased certain minor aspects of the research to justify the heading and conclusions, taking them completely out of context.

Here is a fictional example:

> **Source:** "Research shows modern vehicles are safer than those produced 50 years ago, except in extreme cases of manufacturer's defect or negligence".
>
> **Article:** "Modern vehicles are just as dangerous as the vehicles of 50 years ago"

As dotsamuelswan mentioned, I could see it being *bias*, or possibly classified as *sensationalism*. My question is, would the intentional misquote/paraphrasing constitute a form of plagiarism?

Comment: *Willful ignorance* in most cases.  In any case, it likely falls into some form of *bias.*

Comment: There is a multitude of words to describe this, depending on for what reason it is done, to what end, and with which consequences. It could be anything from *ignorance* to *fabrication*, from *stupidity* to *illiteracy*, from *fraud* to *joke*. The only word that will fit reliably in all circumstances is *lie*. If you need anything more specific, then do be more specific.

Comment: "Misinterpretation": a failure to understand or explain correctly.

Comment: "Misrepresentation" or a synonym:  distortion, exaggeration, fabrication, falsification, misstatement, untruth, adulteration, coloring, lie, mutilation, slant, stretch, twist.

Comment: My take is that it would not technically be "plagiarism", but the original author might have grounds for legal action for libel or some other such claim, and certainly any university administration or journal management might be inclined to fire you or ban you from publication.  (But there is a tiny window for "plagiarism" claims, I suppose.  If you copyright your work (which can be done after the fact) and the (accurate) copying would have been "fair use", likely one can claim that the misrepresentation is not fair use, and so your copyright was infringed.)

Comment: I'd call it *cherrypicking* but Wikipedia calls it [*contextomy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_quoting_out_of_context).  In the context of media, it's ***sensationalism***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, this is not plagiarism. [Plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) is about taking another's work and passing it off as your own.

This is more likely another kind of literary fraud, namely [quoting out of context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_quoting_out_of_context), also known as **[contextomy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contextomy)** as @stevesliva notes in the comments.